# ASM duplicate methods

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to remove all System#exit calls, and it seems to be working, but I end up with method duplicates.

My code looks like this:

```
    JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(input)));
    JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(output)));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    JarEntry entry;

    while ((entry = jis.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int size;

        while ((size = jis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, size);
        }

        bos.close();

        jos.putNextEntry(new JarEntry(entry.getName()));

        if (entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(bos.toByteArray());
            ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);

            ClassTransformer cm = new ClassTransformer(cw);

            ClassNode cn = new ClassNode();
            cr.accept(cn, 0);

            System.out.println("Analyzing bytecode in class " + cn.name);

            List<MethodNode> methods = cn.methods;

            for (MethodNode method : methods) {
                System.out.println("Analyzing bytecode in method " + method.name);

                String[] exceptions = (String[]) method.exceptions.toArray(new String[method.exceptions.size()]);

                cm.visitMethod(method.access, method.name, method.desc, method.signature, exceptions);
            }

            cr.accept(cm, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
            jos.write(cw.toByteArray());
        } else {
            jos.write(bos.toByteArray());
        }
    }

    jos.close();
    jis.close();
```

Both ClassTransformer and MethodTransformer, is custom classes. let me know, if you want me to provide them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should become familiar with the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

The statement

```
cr.accept(cm, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
```

is already doing the entire work. The `ClassReader` will invoke all `visit…` method on the specified `ClassTransformer`, which will do all necessary delegation to the `ClassWriter` when following the standard programming model of this API.

In other words, this entire block

```
ClassNode cn = new ClassNode();
cr.accept(cn, 0);

System.out.println("Analyzing bytecode in class " + cn.name);

List<MethodNode> methods = cn.methods;

for (MethodNode method : methods) {
    System.out.println("Analyzing bytecode in method " + method.name);

    String[] exceptions = (String[]) method.exceptions.toArray(new String[method.exceptions.size()]);

    cm.visitMethod(method.access, method.name, method.desc, method.signature, exceptions);
}
```

is obsolete and since it is looping over all methods and invoking `visitMethod` for each in addition to the statement that already does the entire work, it’s not surprising that you get each method twice.

So just remove that code block.

Well, of course, you may keep the print statement…

---

By the way, you may simplify your code further, by simply passing the `JarInputStream` to the `ClassReader(InputStream)` constructor, without copying to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` first.

A cleaned up version of your code will look like:

```
try(JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(input));
    JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output)) ) {

    JarEntry entry;
    while((entry = jis.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
        jos.putNextEntry(new JarEntry(entry.getName()));

        if (entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(jis);
            ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
            ClassTransformer cm = new ClassTransformer(cw);
            System.out.println("Analyzing bytecode in class " + cr.getClassName());
            cr.accept(cm, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
            jos.write(cw.toByteArray());
        } else {
            jis.transferTo(jos); // Java 9
            /* before Java 9:
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            for(int read; (read = jis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0; )
                jos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I also passed the `ClassReader` to the `ClassWriter`’s constructor. For use cases like this, where only small changes are made, this allows an optimized code generation.